# Odd visual effect (little line shows) when hovering over button in browser

Tags: css, button, hover

We have a few buttons on a web page that have this odd little line show up on the right side when you hover over the button.  It only affects the first two (out of three) buttons.  This could be because there is not fourth button, i.e. the effect may be showing only because there is an adjacent button.  This seems to happen in all browsers.

Attached are some screen shots showing the little line. 
[image: Button1 showing odd line] 
[image: Button2 showing odd line]

I made a [JSFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/57jxzsnf/) showing the problem.

Or here is the Stack JSFiddle, too (didn't know it would do this):

```css
element.style {
    margin-top: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 75px;
}
*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.btn-m {
    background-color: rgb(220, 211, 188);
    border-color: rgb(120, 97, 68);
    color: rgb(69, 39, 0);
}
.btn-xs, .btn-group-xs > .btn {
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 1px 5px;
}
.btn {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.btn-m {
    background-color: rgb(220, 211, 188);
    border-color: rgb(120, 97, 68);
    color: rgb(69, 39, 0);
}
.btn-xs, .btn-group-xs > .btn {
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 1px 5px;
}
.btn {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
input, button, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
button, html input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
button, select {
    text-transform: none;
}
button {
    overflow: visible;
}
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
    color: #000000;
}
a {
    color: #000000;
}
a {
    color: #428bca;
}
body {
    font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif;
}
body {
    font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif;
}
body {
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div style="position: absolute;top: 58px;left: 100px;">
<a href="log.php?Range=Today">
<button class="btn btn-m btn-xs" type="button" style="margin-top:4px; width: 75px; text-decoration: none;" title="Display records for Today only.">Today</button>
</a>

<button class="btn btn-m btn-xs" title="Display records for last 7 days." style="margin-top:4px; width:85px;" type="button">Last 7 Days   </button>

    <a href="">
        <button title="week." type="button">Week</button>
    </a>
    
<a href="log.php?Range=ThisMonth">
<button class="btn btn-m btn-xs" title="Display records from the first of the month through today." style="margin-top:4px; width:85px;" type="button">This Month</button>
</a>
</div>
</body>
```

For the CSS be aware that I just copied and pasted the CSS from the Firebug CSS window.  The computed CSS that I had posted before was not showing all the values.  Yes, the CSS is repetitive; we have a number of different sources/files defining things so they get repeated.  The pasted result from Firebug makes that distinction hard to see, though.  And the pasted version may be inverted?  I.e. the 'inherited from HTML..' stuff at the bottom in the Fiddle is (I am guessing) actually the first thing that gets evaluated, and Firebug just inverts the CSS evaluation order (more useful for humans).

In doing a quick bit of fiddling, it appears that it is coming from the anchor tags.  If I remove the wrapping anchor tag from the button defintion, the line goes away.  (Oddly, on the JSFIddle, the mystery line shows up all the time, even when not hovering.  Makes it a bit easier to see the issue I suppose.)  I also created a new element and stuck it in there for some other testing.  Whatever; the issue is still visible.

Any thoughts on what is causing the line or how to clean it up?

Thanks,
J

Comment: Please post a complete code example so that we can re-create the issue. A jsFiddle or stack snippet is helpful.

Comment: Without your **CSS** a good solution can't be provided. But you can get rid of line using this code `a{text-decoration:none;}` [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3xyhmpeo/)

Comment: You are using `<button>` inside `<a>` so I guess having `text-decoration:none` will be OK. If this works for you I'll post it as answer.

Comment: Will give the 'text-decoration' a shot.  Is there a better way to render button-looking things without <button> and <a>?  Obviously very new to this type of thing.

Comment: @Syed Ali Taqi:  Woot!  Looks like the 'text-decoration: none', when applied to the anchors, fixes the issue.  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I've posted the solution as answer below so if any one else had same problem it would be easy to find solution. Please mark it as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `text-decoration` property of your `<a>` tag to `none` as you are using button inside it.

```
a {
color: #000000;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

**Complete Code**

```css
element.style {
    margin-top: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 75px;
}
*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.btn-m {
    background-color: rgb(220, 211, 188);
    border-color: rgb(120, 97, 68);
    color: rgb(69, 39, 0);
}
.btn-xs, .btn-group-xs > .btn {
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 1px 5px;
}
.btn {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.btn-m {
    background-color: rgb(220, 211, 188);
    border-color: rgb(120, 97, 68);
    color: rgb(69, 39, 0);
}
.btn-xs, .btn-group-xs > .btn {
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 1px 5px;
}
.btn {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
input, button, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
button, html input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
button, select {
    text-transform: none;
}
button {
    overflow: visible;
}
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration:none;

}
body {
    font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif;
}
body {
    font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif;
}
body {
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div style="position: absolute;top: 58px;left: 100px;">
<a href="log.php?Range=Today">
<button class="btn btn-m btn-xs" type="button" style="margin-top:4px; width: 75px; text-decoration: none;" title="Display records for Today only.">Today</button>
</a>

<button class="btn btn-m btn-xs" title="Display records for last 7 days." style="margin-top:4px; width:85px;" type="button">Last 7 Days   </button>

    <a href="">
        <button title="week." type="button">Week</button>
    </a>
    
<a href="log.php?Range=ThisMonth">
<button class="btn btn-m btn-xs" title="Display records from the first of the month through today." style="margin-top:4px; width:85px;" type="button">This Month</button>
</a>
</div>
</body>
```